# Simple Encryption/Decryption Program Using Maps

Tags: c++, encryption, iterator, maps

I'm supposed to be writing a simple program that uses two maps to encrypt/decrypt the string "Hello World". The data for the encryption map is given via command line argument. I've successfully put the data from the dictionary file into a map and I've also got the decryption map ready. However, I can't figure out how to actually make the program do the encryption correctly. My output should be "Fuggy, typegq" given the encryption dictionary that is shown after my code. The format is the first plaintext character is mapped to a second ciphertext character. The output I get is a blank space for the 'H' in Hello World, followed by "ibbv dvwbc." I'm pretty sure the blank space is because my dictionary only includes lowercase letters. How can I improve my code to get the correct output?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<map>
#include<cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

map<char, char> encryptDictionary;
map<char, char> decryptDictionary;
string dictionaryString;
string encryptThis = "Hello world";
fstream file;
int size = encryptThis.size();

file.open(argv[1]);

//Populates encryption dictionary map
while (file >> dictionaryString){
   encryptDictionary[dictionaryString[0]] = dictionaryString[1];
}

//Populates decryption dictionary map
 for(auto itr = encryptDictionary.begin(); itr !=encryptDictionary.end(); itr++){
       decryptDictionary [ itr -> second] = itr -> first;
       }


for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
for (auto itr = encryptDictionary.begin(); itr !=encryptDictionary.end(); itr++) {

   encryptThis[i] = (encryptDictionary.find(encryptThis[i])->second);

}
}

  cout << encryptThis;
  file.close();
return 0;
}
```

This is the dictionary provided

```
an
bx
cs
dq
eu
fk
gj
hf
iz
jm
ko
lg
mw
ni
oy
pl
qa
rp
sr
tb
ud
vh
wt
xe
yv
zc
```

Comment: Don't iterate over the map because the same item is replaced multiple times ('h' becomes 'f', then 'k', etc), so remove the inner loop. You can transform the input string to lower case with `tolower()`.